# Why can't I move my character in unity using newInput package?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, game-development

I'm new to unity and I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iYWpzL9GkM&t=1600s

But when I do the code at [42:00](https://youtu.be/7iYWpzL9GkM?t=2525) and compile my character wont move at all. I wont to believe I did everything exactly as the video explains but I cant figure out how to fix it.
Here is my code

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    //Take and handle input and movement from the character
    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float moveSpeed = 1f;
        public float collisionOffset = 0.05f;
        public ContactFilter2D movementFilter;
        Vector2 movementInput;
        Rigidbody2D rb;
        List<RaycastHit2D> castCollisions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        {
            rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        }
    
        private void FixedUpdate(){
            //If movement input is not 0, try to move
            if(movementInput != Vector2.zero){
                bool success = TryMove(movementInput);
    
                if(!success){
                    success = TryMove(new Vector2(movementInput.x, 0));
                }
    
                if(!success){
                    success = TryMove(new Vector2(0, movementInput.y));
                }
            }
            
        }
    
        private bool TryMove(Vector2 direccion){
            //Check for Potencial Collisions
            int count = rb.Cast(
                direccion, // X and Y values between -1 and 1 that represent the direction from the body to look for collision
                movementFilter, // The setting that determines where a collision can occur on such as layers to collide with
                castCollisions, // Lists of collisions to store the found collisions into after the Cast is finished
                moveSpeed = Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset); // The amount to cast equal to the movement plus an offset
    
            if(count == 0){
                rb.MovePosition(rb.position * direccion * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        void OnMove(InputValue movementValue){
            movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
        }
    
    }
```

If anyone can help I really appreciate it.

Input System: version 1.3.0
Visual Studio Code Editor: version 1.2.5
Test Framework: version 1.1.33
Unity: version 2021.3.7f1

Comment: Try to debug.log the count in try move after its creation. Maybe it's never zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your should change direccion to direction in TryMove.
2. You should make sure you have all your values in the inspector assigned to the according thing. eg. rb should be assigned to your character and your character should have the rigidBody attached to it.

Hope this helps, tell me if it still doesn't work.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then make sure that if you use the old InputSystem as well in another script, then make sure to change the Input Systems to Both in player settings